# Can't make an async request to work on Android activity

Tags: android, json, asynchronous

I have an issue I can't manage to resolve. I'm new to Android development. My app consist of a list view which get information from a `JSON`file via an `HTTP` get request.

This part is ok, it's working. But I cannot manage to do the same with my second activity which consist of a layout displaying information. I planned to pass information between views with intents.

Even if the list view activity is working, I can't use the same functions on the second activity without crashs. I want to make a `HTTP` get request and parse the Json as well.

Bellow are the list view activity & the second activity. What changes I must do to get this work?

ListView Activity : working

```
public class ShopsActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get JSON
    private static String url = "http://webserviceurl";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "shop_name";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS_STRING = "shop_address";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "shop_url";
    private static final String TAG_BOOKLET_URL = "feuilletez";
    TextView shop_address;
    TextView shop_name;
    TextView shop_url;
    ImageButton feuilletez;
    private ListView list;

    private ImageButton button1;
    private ImageButton button2;
    private ImageButton button3;
    private ImageButton button4;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Portrait only
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Remove title bar
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
                this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shops);


        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetJson().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShopsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mise à jour...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            JSONArray array = null;
            try {
                array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id --->" + id);
                 String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                 System.out.println("url --->" + url);
                 String created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                 System.out.println("created_at --->" + created_at);
                 String updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
                 System.out.println("updated_at --->" + updated_at);
                 String name = jsonObject.getString("name");    
                 System.out.println("name --->" + name);
                 JSONArray photos_urls = jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos_urls");
                 System.out.println("photos_urls --->" + photos_urls);
                 String address_string = jsonObject.getString("address_string");
                 System.out.println("address_string --->" + address_string);
                 JSONObject booklet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("booklet");
                 String id_booklet = booklet.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id_booklet --->" + id_booklet);
                 String url_booklet = booklet.getString("url");
                 System.out.println("url_booklet --->" + url_booklet);
                 String created_at_booklet = booklet.getString("created_at");
                 System.out.println("created_at_booklet --->" + created_at_booklet);
                 String updated_at_booklet = booklet.getString("updated_at");
                 System.out.println("updated_at_booklet --->" + updated_at_booklet);
                 String document_url = booklet.getString("document_url");
                 System.out.println("document_url --->" + document_url);
                 String presented = booklet.getString("presented");
                 System.out.println("presented --->" + presented);

                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                 map.put(TAG_ADDRESS_STRING, address_string);
                 map.put(TAG_URL, url);
                 map.put(TAG_BOOKLET_URL, url_booklet);
                 oslist.add(map);
                        }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            return null;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShopsActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.listview_item_row, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                                TAG_ADDRESS_STRING, TAG_BOOKLET_URL }, new int[] { R.id.name_shop,
                                R.id.address_shop});
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ShopsActivity.this, ShopActivity.class);
                    //  Toast.makeText(ShopsActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("shop_url"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        intent.putExtra("shopurl",oslist.get(+position).get("shop_url"));
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();



        }

    }

}
```

TargetActivity : trying to adapt to work as well:

```
public class ShopActivity extends Activity {

    private int userIcon, jewelleryIcon;
    private GoogleMap theMap;
    private LocationManager locMan;
    private Marker userMarker;
    private Marker bijouterie;
    private Button emailButton;
    private long latitude;
    private long longitude;
    private String image1;
    private String image2;
    private ImageButton button1;
    private ImageButton button2;
    private ImageButton button3;
    private ImageButton button4;
    private ImageButton button5;
    private ImageButton catalogue;
    private Button goToMap;
    private String thebooketurl = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
     * @return */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Portrait only
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Remove title bar
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
                this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);



        // View's main buttons

                goToMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mapClick);
                goToMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
                {
                   @Override          
                   public void onClick(View goToMap) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, FullMapActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
                   }
                   });

                button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
                {
                   @Override          
                   public void onClick(View Button1) {
                      finish();//go back to the previous Activity
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backin, R.anim.backout); 
                   }
                   });

                button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
                button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
                {
                   @Override          
                   public void onClick(View Button1) {
                       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        i.setType("message/rfc822");
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"mail.fr"});
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "");
                        try {
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(ShopActivity.this, "Pas de client de messagerie installé sur cet appareil.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    });

                button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
                button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
                {
                   @Override          
                   public void onClick(View Button1) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, PhilosophyActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                   }
                   });

                button4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
                button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
                {
                   @Override          
                   public void onClick(View Button1) {
                       finish();//go back to the previous Activity
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backin, R.anim.backout); 
                   }
                   });

                button5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
                button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
                {
                   @Override          
                   public void onClick(View Button1) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                   }
                   });

                catalogue = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.feuilletez);
                catalogue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
                {
                   @Override          
                   public void onClick(View Button1) {
                       Intent bookleturl = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, PdfReader.class);
                        bookleturl.putExtra("bookleturl", thebooketurl);
                        startActivity(bookleturl);

                       Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, PdfReader.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                   }
                   });

        // Add fonts

           //     Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.ttf");

        // View's items
                 TextView shopAddressTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.shopAddress);
                // shopAddressTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
                 TextView shopNameTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.shopName);
                 TextView shopPhoneTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.shopPhone);
                 TextView shopFaxTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.shopFax);
                 TextView shopHoursTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.shopHours);
                 TextView shopHoursTextView2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.shopHours2);
                 ImageView firstImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firstImage);
                 ImageView secondImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secondImage);


                 // HTTP Request

                 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                 client.get("webserviceurl", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                     @Override
                     public void onSuccess(String response) {
                         System.out.println("this is reponse >" + response);
                     }
                 });

                // Reading text file from assets folder
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader br = null;
                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                            "test.json")));
                    String temp;
                    while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                        sb.append(temp);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        br.close(); // stop reading
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                String myjsonstring = sb.toString();
                Log.d("string: " , myjsonstring);

                JSONArray array = null;
                try {
                    array = new JSONArray(myjsonstring);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
                     String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                     System.out.println("id --->" + id);
                     String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                     System.out.println("url --->" + url);
                     String created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                     System.out.println("created_at --->" + created_at);
                     String updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
                     System.out.println("updated_at --->" + updated_at);
                     String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                     shopNameTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                     System.out.println("name --->" + name);
                     String phone = jsonObject.getString("phone");
                     if(phone == "null")
                         shopPhoneTextView.setText("-");
                     else
                     shopPhoneTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
                     System.out.println("phone --->" + phone);
                     String fax = jsonObject.getString("fax");
                     if(fax == "null")
                         shopFaxTextView.setText("-");
                     else
                         shopFaxTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("fax"));
                     System.out.println("fax --->" + fax);

                     final String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

                     emailButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEmail);  
                     emailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                        {
                        @Override          
                        public void onClick(View Button4) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            i.setType("message/rfc822");
                            if(email == "null")
                                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"mail.fr"});
                             else
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{email});
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "");
                            try {
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                                Toast.makeText(ShopActivity.this, "Pas de client de messagerie installé sur cet appareil.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        });


    //shopEmailTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("email"));
                     System.out.println("email --->" + phone);
                     String website_url = jsonObject.getString("website_url");
                     System.out.println("website_url --->" + phone);
                     String detail = jsonObject.getString("detail");
                     System.out.println("detail --->" + detail);
                     String logo_url = jsonObject.getString("logo_url");
                     System.out.println("logo_url --->" + logo_url);
                     String logo_thumbnail_url = jsonObject.getString("logo_thumbnail_url");
                     System.out.println("logo_thumbnail_url --->" + logo_thumbnail_url);
                     JSONArray photos_urls = jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos_urls");
                     System.out.println("photos_urls --->" + photos_urls);

                     image1 = photos_urls.getString(0);

                     if(image1 != null){
                     new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firstImage))
                        .execute(image1);
                     }

                     image2 = photos_urls.getString(0);

                     if(image2 != null){
                     new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secondImage))
                      .execute(image2);
                     }


                     JSONArray opening_hours = jsonObject.getJSONArray("opening_hours");

                     String hoursTitle = "Horaires d'ouverture :";
                     String lundi = opening_hours.getString(0);
                     if(lundi==null)
                         lundi = "NC";
                     String mardi = opening_hours.getString(1);
                     String mercredi = opening_hours.getString(2);
                     String jeudi = opening_hours.getString(3);
                     String vendredi = opening_hours.getString(4);
                     String samedi = opening_hours.getString(5);

                     shopHoursTextView.setText(hoursTitle+"\nLundi : "+lundi+"\nMardi : "+mardi+"\nMercredi : "+mercredi+"");
                     shopHoursTextView2.setText("Jeudi : "+jeudi+"\nVendredi : "+vendredi+"\nSamedi : "+samedi);




                     System.out.println("opening_hours --->" + opening_hours);
                     String address_string = jsonObject.getString("address_string");
                     shopAddressTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("address_string"));
                     System.out.println("address_string --->" + address_string);

                     JSONObject contact = jsonObject.getJSONObject("contact");
                     String title = contact.getString("title");
                     System.out.println("title --->" + title);
                     String first_name = contact.getString("first_name");
                     System.out.println("first_name --->" + first_name);
                     String last_name = contact.getString("last_name");
                     System.out.println("last_name --->" + last_name);

                     JSONObject address = jsonObject.getJSONObject("address");
                     String id_address = address.getString("id");
                     System.out.println("id --->" + id_address);
                     String url_address = address.getString("url");
                     System.out.println("url --->" + url_address);
                     String created_at_address = address.getString("created_at");
                     System.out.println("created_at_address --->" + created_at_address);
                     String updated_at_address = address.getString("updated_at");
                     System.out.println("updated_at_address --->" + updated_at_address);
                     String street_address = address.getString("street_address");
                     System.out.println("street_address --->" + street_address);
                     String extended_address = address.getString("extended_address");
                     System.out.println("extended_address --->" + extended_address);
                     String postal_code = address.getString("postal_code");
                     System.out.println("postal_code --->" + postal_code);
                     String locality = address.getString("locality");
                     System.out.println("locality --->" + locality);
                     String country_code_alpha2 = address.getString("country_code_alpha2");
                     System.out.println("country_code_alpha2 --->" + country_code_alpha2);
                     JSONArray coordinates = address.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                     System.out.println("coordinates --->" + coordinates);

                     latitude = coordinates.getLong(0);
                     longitude = coordinates.getLong(1);



                     JSONObject booklet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("booklet");
                     String id_booklet = booklet.getString("id");
                     System.out.println("id_booklet --->" + id_booklet);
                     String url_booklet = booklet.getString("url");
                     System.out.println("url_booklet --->" + url_booklet);
                     String created_at_booklet = booklet.getString("created_at");
                     System.out.println("created_at_booklet --->" + created_at_booklet);
                     String updated_at_booklet = booklet.getString("updated_at");
                     System.out.println("updated_at_booklet --->" + updated_at_booklet);
                     String title_booklet = booklet.getString("title");
                     System.out.println("title_booklet --->" + title_booklet);
                     String thumbnail_url = booklet.getString("thumbnail_url");
                     System.out.println("thumbnail_url --->" + thumbnail_url);
                     String document_url = booklet.getString("document_url");
                     System.out.println("document_url --->" + document_url);
                     String presented = booklet.getString("presented");
                     thebooketurl = presented;
                     System.out.println("presented --->" + presented);


                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }





                // Check status of Google Play Services
                int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

                // Check Google Play Service Available
                try {
                    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
                }

        // Google Maps

                userIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
                jewelleryIcon = R.drawable.pointeur;

                if(theMap==null){
                    //map not instantiated yet
                }
                theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
                if(theMap != null){
                    //ok - proceed
                }
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Map
                LatLng BIJOUTERIE = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
                bijouterie = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(BIJOUTERIE)
                .title("title")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(jewelleryIcon))
                .snippet("address"));

                theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 7.5f), 4000, null);             

                  }




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();//go back to the previous Activity
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backin, R.anim.backout);  
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
          ImageView bmImage;

          public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
              this.bmImage = bmImage;
          }

          protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
              String urldisplay = urls[0];
              Bitmap myImage = null;
              try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              myImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myImage, 300, 200, false);;
              return myImage;


          }

          protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
              bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
          }

          public String replaceNull(String input){
              return ((input== null) ? "-" : input);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your logcat as well

Comment: You can set itemClick event on ListView and send the data from clicked item's position using intent and show it in next activity.

Comment: I thought about it, the issue is, I need to download different json because each activity displays different information. I just pass an ID which gives to the second activity to parse the right json object and display it on the second activity.

Comment: @vipul mittal I don't have logcat to post because it would not correspond to the activity I posted. The wrong one was done with tries I've done. The activity I posted here is actually working, but I want to modify it to have http get request working.